# Aligning long equation, ampersand within another function

Tags: align

I have a long equation, and I am using `align` to write the equation on multiple lines.  However, I'd like the alignment point to be *within* another math function.  To be precise, when I try to do the following using `align`, I get an error:

```
\frac{a &+ b}{c} = ...
```

If I do

```
\frac{a + b}{c} &= ...
```

it works fine although it doesn't look like what I want it to.

Is there a way to `align` to an arbitrary point, even within another function call?

Comment: Are the double asterisks meant to indicate the start/end of code? If so you can replace them with a backtick ` to get code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear, there is no possibility to do this. If you do not need that so often, you can always work with phantoms like I do below:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{a + b}{c} &= \dots \\
&a \dots
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a &+ b = \dots \\
&a \dots 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\frac{a + b}{c} = \dots \\
&\hphantom{\frac{a}{c}}\!a \dots 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KiranK. Glad it helped! You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

As supplement to LaRiFaRi answer ... when you need only to move second line more to left with out precise alignment to some point in the first equation, than might become `\MoveEqLeft` handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft
 \frac{a + b}{c} = \dots\\
    &   a \dots
    &   b \dots
\end{align}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even though I ended up using hphantom, the MoveEqLeft will be useful in the future! Thanks.